# How can a valid conclusion be drawn despite the presence of many unknown confounding variables?

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, experiment-design, causality

Specifically, I am trying to understand the above question in the following context:
'John thought that there was a difference in breathing when lying down compared with when sitting on a chair. He decided to test this, using traces from a spirometer.'

Assume that there aren't traces for lying down and sitting on a chair for each person. This means that we're going to have to compare a trace of a certain subject lying down with a trace of ANOTHER subject sitting on a chair (i.e. different subjects being compared in different states.)

How will John test the objective of his experiment?
The situation is obscure. The two different people may inherently already have different breathing characteristics when they are in the same state, and no matter how many variables we control (age, gender, temperature of the room, time of the day, diet before testing etc.), we still simply don't know what the traces are like when both subjects are in the same state (i.e. both lying down, or both sitting up). How can one test John's hypothesis??? What we're doing here seems like I'm ignoring the fact that these are two completely different people.

If the situation were as easy as comparing the spirometer traces for the same subject, I'd just use a chi squared test for each subject and the situation would be easy and done, but that's not the case! Someone please help :(

[Note: please forgive my ignorance if the question wasn't generalised well enough in the introduction, and suggest edits to help.]

Comment: This is a difficult issue. In your case, you *could* measure both on the same person (although e.g. order could matter). More generally, a common approach is [tag:random-allocation].

Comment: This is a very wide topic, may you please provide a summary? I have an exam coming up. Also, assume that we have absolutely no one person with two spirometer traces, if that makes the issue simpler.

Comment: This is the classic setup of an independent samples t-test. If participants are randomized to condition, then in large samples the joint distribution of subject characteristics will be the same for each condition.

Comment: @Noah, may you please expand upon that? I don't fully understand what that means.

Comment: May someone please answer my question by giving some form of description? I know you're all busy, but help would be appreciated please, because I have an important final coming up.

Comment: Let's say we want to avoid confounding by gender. If you randomly assign participants to sitting or laying, not considering their gender, then in large samples the proportion of each gender in each condition will be the same. The same is true of all other variables. This how the most basic of experiments are run and the first experimental design taught in introductory statistics classes. I'm not sure why you think it is obscure or why another commenter though it was a difficult issue.